# Why was the lampstand and altar of sacrifice expected to always be ablaze? What was the symbolic difference?

Tags: exodus, leviticus, traditions

Exodus 27:20 New King James Version

> 20 “And you shall command the children of Israel that they bring you
> pure oil of pressed olives for the light, to cause the lamp to **burn
> continually.**

Leviticus 6:12-13 New King James Version

> 12 And the fire on the altar shall be kept burning on it; it shall not
> be put out. And the priest shall burn wood on it every morning, and
> lay the burnt offering in order on it; and he shall burn on it the fat
> of the peace offerings. 13 **A fire shall always be burning** on the
> altar; **it shall never go out.**

The [Enduring Word Commentary](https://enduringword.com/bible-commentary/exodus-27/) makes a note:

> God never wanted the lamps to lose their fire. Only by a continual
> supply of oil and trimming of the wicks could keep them burning. **We
> can only continue to be on fire for God if we are continually supplied
> with the oil of the Holy Spirit** and are “trimmed” by God to bear
> even more light.

My question is: **Are these purely symbolic? If so, what were they symbolizing and what is the symbolic difference?**

**To clarify:**

- Are there insights into the significance (perhaps symbolic) of the perpetual flames on the lampstand and altar of sacrifice?
- How did these two differ in their representations and what they
  conveyed to the Israelites?

Comment: If needed I will edit my question to focus on only one of these verses!